# SQL Know the most ids in two columns

Tags: sql

I want to know what id_b exist the most times in each id_A. I have this table

```
id_A   id_B
1      1
2      1
2      1
3      1
3      3
3      3
```

And I need a sql command that puts the table like this:

```
id_A id_B
1    1
2    1
3    3
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - sqlcommand can only be used in .net

Comment: What happens when there are two items which are "tied" in count number?

Comment: @GordonLinoff phpmyadmin

Comment: @Hogan its phpmyadmin. when two are tied i need the two id's...

Comment: @EnteiOna -phpmyadmin is not a database platform it is an application -- mysql is a database platform

Comment: @EnteiOna -- needing both ids makes this problem much harder.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is called the "mode" of (the distribution of) the values.

If you only want one, then use can use the ANSI standard function `row_number()` with conditional aggregation:

```
select id_A, id_B as mode_id_B
from (select id_A, id_B, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id_A order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id_A, id_B
     ) ab
where seqnum = 1;
```